# Get value jQuery after .click function jQuery with content dynamic

Tags: jquery, html

I have the next code

HTML

```
<section class="listjobs" style="display: block;">
<div class="jobgroup GigaLab">GigaLab</div>
<div class="jobgroup CraftedContours">CraftedContours</div>
<div class="jobgroup FunPuntos">FunPuntos</div>
<div class="jobgroup Lexplique,LLC">Lexplique,LLC</div>
<div class="jobgroup Arriendas.cl">Arriendas.cl</div>
<div class="jobgroup Scholaroo.com">Scholaroo.com</div>
<div class="jobgroup OctaneNation">OctaneNation</div>
<div class="jobgroup Loogares.com">Loogares.com</div>
<div class="jobgroup AgentPiggy">AgentPiggy</div>
<div class="jobgroup AgentPiggy">AgentPiggy</div>
</section>
```

this is my jQuery.

```
        (function($){

    $('#searchjob').keypress(function(e){
        var search = $.trim($(this).val());

        if (e.which == "13") {

            $.ajax({
                beforeSend: function(){
                    //$('#loading').html(<img src="rutagif" alt="loading" />);
                },
                url:"../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                data:{ action: 'searching_job',data : search },
                //dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data){
                    var jsonresult = JSON.parse(data);
                    var jobs = $('.listjobs');
                    var startups = [];

                    $.each(jsonresult, function(i, item){
                        startups.push(jsonresult[i].meta_value);
                    });

                    startups = $.unique(startups);

                    //console.log(startups);

                    jobs.hide().empty();

                    $.each(startups, function(i, item){
                        var startup = startups[i].replace(" ","");
                        jobs.append("<div id='"+startup+"'class='jobgroup'><h2>"+startups[i]+"</h2><p></p></div>").slideDown();
                    });

                }

            });

            e.preventDefault();

        };

    });
```

This code not found

```
    $(this).click(function(e){
        console.log($(this).text());
    });
```

Also try with $('.lisjobs'), this show an alert but not get the data, also try with $('section.listjobs .jobgroup'), $('.jobgroup') and not found. Any other idea ?

```
 })(jQuery);
```

but not found :/. How to get the value of div with class "jobgroup"?. Any example.

Comment: I think you should change `section.listjobs` with `section.listjobs div.jobgroup`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to get the value of the clicked `jobgroup` you'd do

```
$('section.listjobs .jobgroup').click(function(e){
    var name = $(this).text();
    /* Do something with "name" here */
});
```

But that just sets a variable with the text, it doesn't do anything with it.

**EDIT:** It looks like you load this content through AJAX, in that case you can't bind them at runtime but need to bind them dynamically using `on()`. This code is assuming that `section.listjobs` is NOT loaded through AJAX.

```
$('section.listjobs').on('click', '.jobgroup', function(e){
    var name = $(this).text();
    /* Do something with "name" here */
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bjLxS/1/)

You could also bind them using the first method, but then you need to run that script AFTER the elements have been added to the DOM, that is, at the end of the ajax `success` function. I'd still go with `on()`.

Comment: With the HTML you posted it should: http://jsfiddle.net/bjLxS/ If it doesn't work, your HTML doesn't actually look like the one you posted or you have a Javascript error somewhere else on your page that prevents this script from running.

Comment: ...or possibly you don't have Jquery loaded on your page. What's your exact error message?

Comment: I have just copy my code, jQuery loaded because after to use .click function I'm use .ajax function.

Comment: It looks like you load your content dynamically. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The function seems to be working. You're dumping the full text into the variable "name" - you might want to output it somewhere so you can see the result (maybe using *console.log()* ).

You might also want to change the field that is clicked - currently you've got it set to the "listjobs" section - you can link it down to the specific job group if you want to output that.

Example code:

```
$('section.listjobs .jobgroup').click(function(e){
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong context. `this` is the event, not the `div`. You'll want to select by `this.id`, which is the id of the control that fired the event.

So, you can do:

```
var name = $('#' + this.id).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.jobgroup').click(function(){
var tmpHtml = $(this).html();
alert(tmpHtml);
});
```